# Hibernate createSqlQuery setting variable

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I have a mysql query like this to get the row numbers.

```
set @rank = 0; 
select @rank := @rank + 1 as rank,id,name from test
```

In hibernate 3 ':=' was a problem.

```
session.createSQLQuery("set @rank = 0; 
                        select @rank := @rank + 1 as rank,id,name from test");
```

i switch to hibernate 3 to 4 and used escape character.

```
session.createSQLQuery("set @rank = 0; 
                        select @rank \\:= @rank + 1 as rank,id,name from test");
```

Now another exception occured. It gives the exception:

```
"Parameter rank does not exist as a named parameter"
```

I tried this:

```
 session.createSQLQuery("select :rank \\:= :rank + 1 as rank,
                         ID,NAME,SURNAME from test").setInteger("rank", 0)
```

This time it gives this exception:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':= 0 + 1 as rank,id,
name from test' at line 1
```

Any idea how can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using doReturningWork() you gain the access to the plain JDBC connection.
Then you should split your SQL into 2 executions (set and select):

```
final Object queryResultObject = session.doReturningWork(new ReturningWork<ReturnObjectType>() {

  @Override
  public ReturnObjectType execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {

    final Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    statement.execute("set @rank = 0");

    final ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(
                                      "select @rank := @rank + 1 as rank,id,name
                                       from test");

    ReturnObjectType result = /* transform ResultSet into return value */

    return result;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate doesn't support database specific SQL syntaxes or SQL local variables.

From what I see you don't even want to select some entity, so you just need an aggregation query:

```
select count(t), t.id, t.name 
from Test t
group by t.id, t.name
```

Assuming you have a Test entity mapped to the test table.

Comment: Are you sure there is no way using local variables with hibernate? This is sad.

Comment: You can always use native SQL, even with Hiberante so you can give that a try.

Comment: I dont understand you. I think i was using native SQL with "createSQLQuery". Can you explain your comment a little bit please?

Comment: Check [doWork](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#doWork%28org.hibernate.jdbc.Work%29) to get access to the current Connection, where you can write plain old JDBC.

Comment: i tried doReturningWork() still doesnt let me to use local sql variable